# Does an object retrieved from a list get a copy of that object or a reference to it?

Tags: vb.net, reference

In VB.net,  when I retrieve a value from a list do I get a copy of that value or a reference to it?

```
dim blah as someObject
dim listOfBlahs as list(of someObject)
listOfBlah.add(new someObject(1))

blah = listOfBlah(0)
blah.setValue = 500
```

Does the value of listOfBlah(0) get updated to 500?

Comment: Depends on if it's a value type or reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blah will point to the same memory location as listOfBlah(0).  Setting a property on the object at that location will affect the object in memory at that location.  If you set blah = someOtherObject later, then the object in the memory location for listOfBlah(0) will not be affected because effectively you're pointing blah at a different object.

This is generally the case, but for a more in depth discussion, you should take a look at Microsoft's documentation on value types and reference types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711899(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the value of listOfBlah(0) is updated as 500. Objects are reference type.
In your code

**blah** is pointing of listOfBlah(0) object. Whatever value is change to **blah** is updated to listOfBlah(0)